# How to use pandas rolling window with custom frequency and data folding

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I want to use a rolling window with pandas series, but I want to apply it every certain period of time. Therefore, not every sample in the series data.
Such rolling window would therefore be applied with a certain frequency.

*ex. Get a mean of 60s of data, every 30s.*

I was able to achieve this using both rolling and resampling

`data = values.rolling('60s').mean().resample('30s').mean()`

But this is obviously wasting resources, since it **first calculates rolling window** of very high sampling frequency, and **afterwards it downsamples** it to a much lower frequency.

Now, there used to be a *'freq'* parameter a while back in the rolling window method, but now it is gone and I don't know how to optimize this code, not to do calculations with high sampling frequency, just to downsample it afterwards.

`data = values.rolling('60s', freq= '30s').mean()`

Isn't there a method to achieve this functionality in the rolling window method, or the resample method? Is there a way to fold the data in the analysis window.

EDIT:

**Can this be performed by an indexer somehow, I was not able to find an example?**